# Is there support for Vaadin's declarative ui framework in Intellij or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin7

We have a project written in Vaadin and we want to start using "[Declarative UI](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-declarative.html)"
Our developers use both Intellij and Eclipse.  When we started writing our first declarative ui we noticed that the .html portion did not do any code completion.  For example Intellij did not suggest "caption" as a property for the following entry...

```
    <vaadin-tree _id="mytree" caption="My Tree"
                 width-auto height-full/>
```

Perhaps I misconfigured our Vaadin project and the IDE does support this?  Or is this not a feature yet?

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for IntelliJ, Eclipse and Netbeans. I'm not sure how well each support the declarative syntax in html files. The plugin for Eclipse is provided by Vaadin, and you can install a gui designer plugin alongside, which lets you edit the html files in wysiwyg mode, with all kinds of support for the html-format of course. It is commercial, though, but with a trial period. Works pretty well, but, editing the html files by hand is also easy and quite effective with the short roundtrip you have in Eclipse+tomcat, so I'm not sure if it's worth it, unless you need non-programmers to create gui-prototypes for you, or just happens to love wysiwyg-stuff.

When it comes to Netbeans and IntelliJ I haven't used the plugins, I think they're primary function is to set up the project with libraries, and I prefer to use the Vaadin maven archetypes or Spring start for that.